# Linq with Included Subquery is failing on EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using MySQL DB with ef core all works fine but the following query does nto return expected result.

```
    var query = _context.ServiceData.
        Include(x => x.Country)
        .Include(x=>x.Country.CountryLocale)
        .Where(x=>x.Country.CountryLocale.Any(l=>l.Locale == "en-US"));
```

After executing and doing

```
query.First().Country.CountryLocale.Count // Returns count of greater than 1 when expected count is 1
```

The table only has 2 entries and the above pulls both when only 1 is expected.

Table Layout

```
Id   Name Locale
1    Test   en-US
2    Test   en-GB
```

All examples I have seen seem to suggest doing it how I am doing it so not sure what I am missing.

Here is the sql generated by above Linq

```
SELECT `a`.`Id`, `a`.`ServiceDataCode`, `a`.`CountryId`, `a`.`Enabled`, `a`.`LastUpdated`, `a`.`TimezoneId`, `c`.`Id`, `c`.`DialingCode`, `c`.`Enabled`, `c`.`IsoNumeric`, `c`.`IsoThreeLetterCode`, `c`.`IsoTwoLetterCode`, `c`.`LastUpdated`, `c0`.`Id`, `c0`.`IsoTwoLetterCode`, `c0`.`LastUpdated`, `c0`.`Locale`, `c0`.`Name`
FROM `ServiceData` AS `a`
INNER JOIN `CountryData` AS `c` ON `a`.`CountryId` = `c`.`Id`
LEFT JOIN `CountryLocale` AS `c0` ON `c`.`IsoTwoLetterCode` = `c0`.`IsoTwoLetterCode`
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM `CountryLocale` AS `c1`
    WHERE (`c`.`IsoTwoLetterCode` = `c1`.`IsoTwoLetterCode`) AND (`c1`.`Locale` = 'en-US'))
ORDER BY `a`.`Id`, `c`.`Id`, `c0`.`Id`
```

I guess a stored procedure is another option but wanted to do it without.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is an object query with a right paths of country and specific country locale that belong to first service data:

```
using (var query = _context.ServiceData
    .Include("Country.CountryLocale")
    .Where(x => x.ServiceData.CountryId == x.Country.Id)
    .Where(x => x.Country.IsoTwoLetterCode == x.Country.CountryLocale.IsoTwoLetterCode)
    .Where(x => x.Country.CountryLocale.Locale == "en-US"))
{
    query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but still pulls both en-US and en-GB from CountryLocale table

Comment: You are welcome. I have change for more suitable filter, so you could take a look the changes.

Comment: Thanks again tried it but can't do x.Country.IsoTwoLetterCode == x.Country.CountyLocale.IsoTwoletterCode as Country.CountryLocale is a ICollection.

Comment: I understand. So part of the filter should like this? .Where(x => x.Country.CountryLocale.Any(=> l.Locale == "en-US")

Comment: Thanks again but still same result now the sql generated is same as in my original question but an Left join LEFT JOIN `CountryLocale` AS `c0` ON `c`.`IsoTwoLetterCode` = `c0`.`IsoTwoLetterCode` and INNER JOIN `CountryData` AS `c` ON `a`.`CountryId` = `c`.`Id`does not see right I am sure you would agree.

Comment: Yes. The point of view is on how to make distinct result, with distinct relationship. So you must select only one row of CountryLocale that match CountryData (one to one relationship).

Comment: Agreed that is the point but the SQL generated does not do that.

Comment: I believe you have to make sure that each CountryData related to single CountryLocale. (One-to-one relationship)

Comment: I believe that would not then allow multiple locale codes.